# Why can't I insert all values from my HTML table into my firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The thing is that when I enter values one by one into my `realtime database`, then the values get inserted succesfully.

```
var db_values = {
    "col 1": "abc",
    "col 2": "def",
    "col 3": "ghi",
    "col 4": "jkl"
};
push(ref(db,"table1/"),db_values);
```

Now when I apply the same logic in my HTML table:

```
for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++){
    var db_values = {
        "col 1": table.rows[i].cells.item(0).innerText,
        "col 2": table.rows[i].cells.item(1).innerText,
        "col 3": table.rows[i].cells.item(2).innerText,
        "col 4": table.rows[i].cells.item(3).innerText
    };
    push(ref(db,"table1/"),db_values);
}
```

some of the values are skipped, i.e., not all values from the table are inserted into my database. I've checked for errors in my `console`, but there are none. Where am I going wrong? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the number of rows in your table, you are potentially firing off hundreds of "floating promises" from the `push()` line. They are floating because they have no actions chained to their resolution using `then()`, `catch()` or `await`. Additionally, because your client code is firing off so many requests, the server may not correctly acknowledge all of them.

To mitigate this problem, you can batch the requests together using [the `update()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields). In the below code sample, instead of submitting data to the server on every loop iteration, it assembles the data into one object and then commits it all at once to the server.

```
const tableRef = ref(db, "table1");
const tableData = {};

for (let i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++) {
  const db_values = {
    "col 1": table.rows[i].cells.item(0).innerText,
    "col 2": table.rows[i].cells.item(1).innerText,
    "col 3": table.rows[i].cells.item(2).innerText,
    "col 4": table.rows[i].cells.item(3).innerText
  }

  const rowRef = push(tableRef); // note missing second argument!
  tableData[rowRef.key] = db_values;
}

update(tableRef, tableData)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("uploaded table successfully!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("failed to upload table", err);
  });
```